# Can I combine a bunch of if statements into an object?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have an ArrayList with several thousand single line sentences that I would like to search for roughly 50 key words.  If it contains one of these key words, I want it to add a double that corresponds to that key word to an array.  Once all the array has been checked for matches, I want to sum up the total of the array.

Currently I have something similar to this except the arraylist and double variable lists are much larger:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class searchArrayList {

public static void main(String[] args){


String subject2 = "The color of the ball is blue."; 
String subject3 = "The building is white.";
String subject4 = "Red is my favorite color.";  
String subject5 = "Black and blue are the team colors";



    ArrayList<Double> arrlist = new ArrayList<Double>();
    ArrayList<Double> difflist = new ArrayList<Double>();

    double Black = 10.1;
    double Blue = 1.6;
    double Red = 11.4;
    double White = 4.3;

    String[] subjectArray = {subject2,subject3,subject4,subject5};

    for (String subjects: subjectArray)
    {
        if (subjects.toUpperCase().contains("BLUE"));
        System.out.println(Blue+ "Blue ");
        arrlist.add(Blue);
        if (subjects.toUpperCase().contains("BLACK"));
        System.out.println(Black+" Black");
        arrlist.add(Black);
        if (subjects.toUpperCase().contains("WHITE"));
        System.out.println(White+" White");
        arrlist.add(White);
        if (subjects.toUpperCase().contains("RED"));
        System.out.println(Red+" Red");
        arrlist.add(Red);
    }
    System.out.println(sum(arrlist));
}

public static double sum(ArrayList<Double>arrlist)
{
  double result = 0;
  for (double number:arrlist)
  result += number;
  return result;
    }


   }
```

This does what I need it to, but I was wondering if there is a better or more intuitive way to do this?  Could I combine the if statements to a single object / class and then call that class to search the array?  Would it be better to use a switch statement?  I tried regex for doing the searches but .contains seems to work just as well.

Comment: You can't achieve the same with switch-case, your solution seems OK. But,there can be a better one...

Comment: Firstly, it would be better to move all the words you are searching in array too.
Then to get count of each word you can use double[][]  array and save there related values. Or hashmap.

Comment: Agree with Orest. You could do this without all the if statements if you put the search words in an array also.

Comment: Okay, so create an ArrayList of all the key words? How would I search each element of the SubjectArrayList by the KeywordArrayList?

Comment: *This  does what I need it to* I don't think so, there is a semicolon (;) after each `if` statement, so all the lines after the `if`s will be executed.

Comment: Right, because I want it to find any occurrence of any of the key words.  So even if it is true for one of the statements, I would want it to check for the rest of the keywords.

Comment: I think this kind of question belongs to [codereview](http://www.codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Several thousand?  I hope you are reading those in from a file, and not hard-coding them as shown in your example :-)

Comment: Actually, if you read the sentences from a text file, then you wouldn't even _need_ an array (or any other kind of collection).  You'd read in one line of text, search it for each of the 50 words, read the next line of text, search it, ... until you reached the end of the file.

Comment: They are email subjects from an IMAP mailbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use an array (or a collection) containing your keyword-double associations, and loop over this array:

```
public class Keyword {
    private String value;
    private double points;

    ...
}

private Keyword[] keywords = new Keyword[] {
    new Keyword("BLUE", 1.6),
    new Keyword("BLACK", 10.1),
    ...
}

for (String subject : subjectArray) {
    for (Keyword keyword : keywords) {
        if (subject.toUpperCase().contains(keyword.getValue())) {
            System.out.println(keyword.getPoints() + " " + keyword.getValue());
            arrlist.add(keyword.getPoints());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Very nice, I will give this a try.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to leave a comment, but wouldn't this be more efficient than converting the string to uppercase?

```
org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(String, String)
```

Documentation for the library: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html